# Unable to convert wxPython based GUI to .exe file using pyinstaller in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, pyinstaller

I have been trying to convert my wxPython based python script into a .exe file using PyInstaller but I have not been successful yet. A .exe file is created after the conversion but an errors message saying "Failed to execute script main" pops us as soon as I click on the .exe file.

My code is as follow :

```
import wx
import sys

class MyAppWindow(wx.Frame):



    def __init__(self, title='Path Finder'):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, 111, title, size=(640,480))

        filemenu = wx.Menu()
        filemenu.Append(1,"&About","Create a new file")
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        filemenu.Append(2,"&Quit","Quit the Application")
        #Creating File menu 
        viewmenu = wx.Menu()
        viewmenu.Append(3,"&Shrink","Reduce size to half")
        viewmenu.Append(4,"&Maximize","Maximize window")
        viewmenu.Append(5,"&Full screen","Switch to full screen mode")
        viewmenu.Append(6,"&Reset","Reset View")
        #Creating view menu
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        menubar.Append(filemenu,"&File")
        menubar.Append(viewmenu,"&View")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        #Fitting File and edit in menu bar
        panel2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, 7, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)
        panel2.SetValue("Hello World! \nI am trying to make .exe files using Python!")
        # Created Panels
        vbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        #vbox1.Add(panel1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        vbox1.Add(panel2, 2, wx.EXPAND)
        #vbox1.Add(panel3,1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(vbox1)
        #Sizr to adjust panel 

        wx.EVT_MENU(self, 2, self.onQuit)
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, 3, self.onViewShrink)
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, 4, self.onViewMaximize)
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, 5, self.onViewFullScreen)
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, 6, self.onViewReset)
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, 1, self.OnAbout) 
        #Associating the menu buttons with their respective functions 
        self.Show()



    def onQuit(self, e):
        print("Good bye!")
        self.Close()
    #Quits the GUI

    def onViewReset(self,e):
        self.ShowFullScreen(False)
        self.SetSize((640,480))
        self.Center()
    #Restes the GUI to center

    def onViewFullScreen(self,e):
        self.ShowFullScreen(True)
    #Full Screen 

    def onViewMaximize(self,e):
        self.Maximize(True)
    #Maximises the GUI 

    def onViewShrink(self,e):
        msize = []
        for i in self.GetSize():
            msize.append(int(0.75*i))
        self.SetSize(msize)
    #Shrinks the GUI

    def OnAbout(self, e):
        d = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Program to learn Python to exe conversion\n"
                       ,"Python to exe using PyInstaller", wx.OK)
        d.ShowModal()  # show the dialog
        d.Destroy() 
    #About menu 

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
myApp = wx.App()
myFrame = MyAppWindow()
myApp.MainLoop() 

#End of Python script
```

The command I typed in command prompt is as follow: 
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed MyAppWindow.py

Message displayed in the command prompt is as follow:

```
829 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1
830 INFO: Python: 2.7.11
833 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.16299
838 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Smit\workspace\Amobeo_GUI2exe\src\MyAppWindow.spec
845 INFO: UPX is not available.
856 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Smit\\workspace\\Amobeo_GUI2exe\\src',
 'C:\\Users\\Smit\\workspace\\Amobeo_GUI2exe\\src']
857 INFO: checking Analysis
871 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
873 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
892 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
1178 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
1191 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\smit\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\system\scripts\python.exe
1549 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4967_none_acd2fb3be1d90a9f.manifest
1554 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_acd388d7e1d8689f.manifest
1560 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9317_none_acce041fe1dd7bc9.manifest
1937 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9317_none ...
1942 INFO: Found manifest C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9317_none_08e0939fa840d57b.manifest
2012 INFO: Searching for file msvcr90.dll
2015 INFO: Found file C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9317_none_08e0939fa840d57b\msvcr90.dll
2035 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll
2098 INFO: Found file C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9317_none_08e0939fa840d57b\msvcp90.dll
2128 INFO: Searching for file msvcm90.dll
2159 INFO: Found file C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9317_none_08e0939fa840d57b\msvcm90.dll
2560 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4967_none_acd2fb3be1d90a9f.manifest
2570 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_acd388d7e1d8689f.manifest
2580 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9317_none_acce041fe1dd7bc9.manifest
2592 INFO: Adding redirect Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30729, 9317)
3097 INFO: Caching module hooks...
3129 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Smit\workspace\Amobeo_GUI2exe\src\MyAppWindow.py
3175 INFO: Loading module hooks...
3179 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
11202 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
11204 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
11225 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
11417 INFO: Looking for eggs
11418 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\smit\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\system\scripts\python27.dll
11420 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[BindingRedirect(name=u'Microsoft.VC90.CRT', language=None, arch=u'amd64', oldVersion=(9, 0, 21022, 8), newVersion=(9, 0, 30729, 9317), publicKeyToken=u'1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b')]
11437 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Smit\workspace\Amobeo_GUI2exe\src\build\MyAppWindow\warnMyAppWindow.txt
11543 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\Smit\workspace\Amobeo_GUI2exe\src\build\MyAppWindow\xref-MyAppWindow.html
11834 INFO: checking PYZ
11836 INFO: Building PYZ because out00-PYZ.toc is non existent
11838 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Smit\workspace\Amobeo_GUI2exe\src\build\MyAppWindow\out00-PYZ.pyz
12781 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Smit\workspace\Amobeo_GUI2exe\src\build\MyAppWindow\out00-PYZ.pyz completed successfully.
13014 INFO: checking PKG
13016 INFO: Building PKG because out00-PKG.toc is non existent
13018 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
13146 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30729, 9317)
18030 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
18073 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\smit\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\system\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
18076 INFO: checking EXE
18079 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
18081 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
18084 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\Smit\workspace\Amobeo_GUI2exe\src\dist\MyAppWindow.exe
19056 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.
```

(Image: [Message displayed in command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di9qh.png))

The above procedure creates two folders in my source folders, namely 'build' and 'dist'. An exe file called MyAppWindow.exe is created inside the 'dist' folder. However, the following error message pops up when I click on it:

Fatal Error!
"Failed to execute MyAppWindow"
(Image: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8juM.png))

My GUI looks like this when I run the Python script: 
[GUI created by the Python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhwXq.png)

I am using Python 2.7.11 --  64-bit on Windows

I would be glad for your help. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @cpburnz Thank you so much for your suggestion. I have added the error and log in the question.

Comment: Do you have to use pyinstaller?  I've had considerably better luck with guis written in wx when I used py2exe.  It even works with 64-bit python as of the most recent commits in the SVN Repo.

Comment: @g.d.d.c Thank you so much for your suggestion. _py2exe_ worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Windows 10 Pro 64bit:

- Downloaded and installed Winpython Zero 2.7.13 64 bit ([Link](https://github.com/winpython/winpython/releases/tag/1.7.20170401), very convenient, is portable, activate by clicking/executing "WinPython Command Prompt.exe", no messing around with virtualenv, will not touch your system Python, just delete folder when no longer needed)
- `pip install wxPython`, installs the newest wx
- It is best to use the latest version of PyInstaller (development snapshot, [as suggested in the PyInstaller doc](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)):

`pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop`

- Freezing (`--clean` can be helpful when the proper settings have not been found yet):

`pyinstaller --clean --windowed --onefile app.py`

The app looked like in your screenshot.

I had first the same error message as you had. Looked into the warnings file (`11437 INFO: Warnings written to …`), it turned out that I forgot to pip install wxPython.